# Run Mercury on Xampp portable

Tags: email, apache-http-server, smtp, xampp

I do use xampp-portable-windows-x64-8.0.3-0-VS16. But Mercury was disabled and `\xampp\MercuryMail\` folder was empty. So I copied files from install version and enabled Mercury in `xampp-controll.ini`. Now when I try send email I get: `Could not send email: unknown`. So I do not know if problem is in my code, or that I use portable version, or Mercury does not work as SMTP local server.

There are manuals how to send mail using gmail, but I would like to use simply localhost. Do I need another SMTP app? Thanks for any hint!